# Constructing Matrix in Matlab with Specific Requirements

Tags: matrices, matlab

I need to construct a matrix A whose diagonal is a[i,i]= 2; the sub-diagonals a[i+1,i] = a[i,i+1] = −1/2. All other entries of A are zero. The size must be changeable, I need to make one with dimensions of 50, 100, and 200. I know how to create A matrix with a diagonal of 2 of any size, but not sure how to do the sub-diagonals. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a tri-diagonal matrix and there is probably a built in Matlab command for it. Alternatively write a function with input variable N (the matrix dimension) and use a for loop to populate the off diagonals.

Comment: Simplest way: `n=5;` `A=toeplitz([2 0.5 zeros(1,n-2)])`. Using the `diag` function: `A=diag(2+zeros(n,1))+diag(0.5+zeros(n-1,1),-1)+diag(0.5+zeros(n-1,1),1)`.

Comment: Or just using linear indexing: `n=5;` `A=zeros(n);` `A(1:n+1:end)=2;` `A(2:n+1:end)=0.5;` `A(n+1:n+1:end)=0.5`.

Comment: Cool thanks! What if I want to make a vector b = [1, 2, 2, ..., 2]' in the command window?

Comment: `n=10;b=2*ones(n, 1);b(1)=1`